# Python - Date notation to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, cursor, date

I'm a complete beginner trying to update some fields in an attribute table (i.e. an ArcMap Shapefile) using Python tool. My goal it to update the values from this column to another date notation.

Right now the fields look like this:

> 91/02/25
>    93/01/21
>
> 96/06/14
>   ...

The dates need to be replaced to the following format MM/DD/YYY. There are also some spaces (as shown above in the example) that I would like to replace to something like "No date available".

This is what I wrote:

```
for row in updateCursor:

    theWrongDate = row.RPT_DTE
    theRightDateList = theWrongDate.split("/")
    year = '19' + str(theRightDateList[0])
    month = theRightDateList[1]
    day = theRightDateList[2]
    theWrongDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year
    updateCursor.updateRow(row)
```

and Python gives me an error message:

```
"month = theRightDateList[1]
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

Comment: You're missing a "Y" in your format. Right now this looks like a pure Python question.

Comment: Just below the line where you create theRightDateList, add a line to "print(theRightDateList)". Does the console result look something like ['91','02','25'] ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Some fields contained a space that I replaced by "XX/XX/XXXX". I added the line print(theRightDateList) and it returned all records (example of one: [u'95', u'11', u'08']).

Comment: Now, my problem is that the dates are not updated in the column.

Answer (score 2):

If you split an empty value, it won't have anything at index 1. You can use an if statement to check this:

```
for row in updateCursor:

    theWrongDate = row.RPT_DTE
    theRightDateList = theWrongDate.split("/")

    if len(theRightDateList) == 3:
        year = '19' + str(theRightDateList[0])
        month = theRightDateList[1]
        day = theRightDateList[2]
        theNewDate = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(month, day, year)

        # verify I have the next couple lines correct
        row.setValue(RPT_DTE, theNewDate)
        updateCursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Hello Nate, thanks for your help. I did change the space or empty value by the default "XX/XX/XXXX". It worked. However, the code does not change the date notation to MM/DD/YYYY. It remains as YY/MM/DD

Comment: Any suggestions why the below lines aren't updating the fields?                                                                             theWrongDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year
updateCursor.updateRow(row)

Comment: @Nico13  It looks like you figured it out, but generally you need to make the changes by setting the value, and then save your changes by updating the row. If something in the code above needs to be different, please hit the "edit" button and make the changes so others in the future can see what worked. Thanks.